# PyQt5 - Why my label is only showing the last line in my file?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qlabel, qpushbutton

I'm new in pyqt5 and I'm working on a gui that runs tasks from a txt file (each line is a task) i have a QLabel(txt_task_user) where i want to display line by line, and the QPushButton(user_f_b) that i want to display the next line whenever i click on it.

here is the file :

task1

task2

task3

task4

task5

task6

task7

task8

task9

task10

I tried this but i don't understand why it only shows the last line (task10) when i click the QPushButton  :

```
def __init__(self) :
    super(Lister, self).__init__()
    loadUi("lister.ui", self)
    self.user_f_b.clicked.connect(self.execute_user_f)

def execute_user_f(self) :
    with open("task.txt", "r") as f :
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines :
            self.txt_task_user.setText(str(line))
```

i've been searching on the net i found out that i maybe should use signals but i have no idea how to do that i found nothing interesting on the net.

Comment: Used append will do job for you.

Comment: i've already tried append but i keep getting this error : 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You need something like this  _text = []

Comment: thank you for your support, why do i need a list ? and where do i need to add that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self) :
    super(Lister, self).__init__()
    loadUi("lister.ui", self)
    self.user_f_b.clicked.connect(self.execute_user_f)
    self.counter = 0
    self.taskList = []
    with open("task.txt", "r") as f :
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines :
            self.taskList.append(line)

def execute_user_f(self) :
    self.txt_task_user.setText(self.taskList[self.counter])
    self.counter += 1
```

Comment: oh sorry, i misunderstand your question. i eddited it now. i hope it works properly, i couldn't try it because of loadUi thing.

Comment: thank you very much it works better but it starts from the second line and when i finish reading all lines and i click one more time i wanna avoid this error : list index out of range

Comment: What do you mean by "it starts from the second line"?

Comment: I edited again... chaned the last two lines’ order. Also if you want to continue after the last task, you need to make zero the counter after the last task.

Comment: @lufsasc it works, you are a legend thank you very much !!

Comment: @lufsasc i tried to continue after the last task with this test but it didn't work.any idea please ?
            if line == "" :
                self.counter = 0

Comment: if self.counter == len(self.taskList) -1 : self.counter = 0. Add this the end of the func.

Comment: @lufsasc thank you very much it works but it ignores the last line

Comment: Then... if self.counter == len(self.taskList) : self.counter = 0

Comment: If you are not interested in the current line count, you can also use `itertool.cycle` which will infinitely iterate through the list restarting from the beginning when it's reached the end.